# Delete entire row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I written below code to delete rows with no values in columns A , F and G.

```
Sub DeleteRawBlank()

  Dim Cnt As Long
  Dim RowCnt As Integer

  RowCnt = Worksheets("Raw").UsedRange.Rows.Count

  Worksheets("Raw").Activate

  For Cnt = RowCnt To 2 Step -1
   If Trim(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(Cnt, "A").Value) <> "" And  
      Trim(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(Cnt, "F").Value) <> "" And 
      Trim(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(Cnt, "G").Value) <> "" Then
         Rows(Cnt).Delete
   End If
 Next Cnt
End Sub
```

But it does not work . Any help please

Answer (score 0):

You should use integer values for columns within the `.Cells` property.

You should also take advantage of using the [`With...End With` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

```
Sub delete_row()
    Dim Cnt As Long
    Dim RowCnt As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsRaw As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRaw = wb.Worksheets("Raw")

    With wsRaw
        RowCnt = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Cnt = RowCnt To 2 Step -1
            If Trim(.Cells(Cnt, 1).Value) <> "" And _
               Trim(.Cells(Cnt, 6).Value) <> "" And _
               Trim(.Cells(Cnt, 7).Value) <> "" Then
                Rows(Cnt).Delete
            End If
        Next Cnt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why , but even your code also does not delete rows.

Comment: Then it must be a problem with your `If` statement and what you're expecting it to evaluate vs what it's actually evaluating. Do you only want to delete rows where there is data in columns A, F and G?

Comment: If condition is fine and  "Rows(Cnt).Delete" is also getting executed, but row does not get deleted.

Comment: Hmm, if the `If` statement is working as expected and the `.Delete` line of code is executing, I have no idea why the row is not actually deleting - it was working when tested my end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `= Empty` instead of `<> ""`

`<> ""` will  return `True` if the `Cell` has some data in it.

```
 Sub DeleteRawBlank()

      Dim Cnt As Long
      Dim RowCnt As Integer

      RowCnt = Worksheets("Raw").UsedRange.Rows.Count

      Worksheets("Raw").Activate

      For Cnt = RowCnt To 2 Step -1
           If Trim(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(Cnt, "A").Value) = Empty And _
              Trim(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(Cnt, "F").Value) = Empty And _
              Trim(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(Cnt, "G").Value) = Empty Then

                Rows(Cnt).Delete

           End If
      Next Cnt
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will delete rows only in case when all cells in columns `A`,`F`,`G` will not be blank. So, if you need to delete rows for empty cells in `A`,`F`,`G` then you shall use `=` instead of `<>` in your code, and it will works fine.
Also, you may face with another problem, `integer` type of variable has a limited range (from -32768 to 32767), so if count of rows of your used range will be out of this range then you will receive an error.
Also, pay attention to `usedrange.rows.count` or `usedrange.columns.count` in case when used range not starts from `A1`, because `UsedRange.Rows.Count` counts the numbers of rows inside used range, not counts the rows in worksheet, so count of rows in used range not always will be equal to the last used row in sheet.

I have tryied to simplify your code, and I think that it shall work fine for you:

```
Sub DeleteRawBlank()
    Dim Cnt&, RowCnt&
    With Worksheets("Raw")
      RowCnt = .Cells.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row
      For Cnt = RowCnt To 2 Step -1
         If WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Cells(Cnt, "A") & .Cells(Cnt, "F") & .Cells(Cnt, "G")) = "" Then
           .Rows(Cnt).Delete
         End If
      Next Cnt
    End With
End Sub
```

and one more thing, `trim` will remove only spaces from left and right sides, but will not remove redundant spaces inside string, so if you need to remove all redundant spaces then you shall use `WorksheetFunction.Trim`
so, it will be like in example below:

`trim(" A     B")` will return   `"A     B"`
`trim$("A     B ")` will return  `"A     B"` 
`WorksheetFunction.Trim("    A     B    ")` will return `"A B"`