# Loop through a range and delete row if certain condition is met

Tags: vba

I am a little bit confused, I was trying to loop through a range of cells, and check if this cell value equals other value stored in the variable, if not, I want to delete the whole row. It is starting with last row in the range, but when I run this macro, it stops after first value, and I want to keep on looping through other values. If I will manually run it again, it will work, but then it will stop on the first cell where cell.value = id1 or id2. Is there a "else continue" in vba? or else next cell? I was trying to play with this and googling it, but no luck.

The IDs values I had in my example was just; 3 & 4. While range of values I was looping through was just 1 to 6

#as suggested below when I changed ws2.Range("A" & LastRow) to a  ws2.Range("A1:A" & LastRow) it kind of works, but it doesnt loop through all cells at once, but I need to run this macro twice... to remove all unwanted cells... this is confusing

```
Sub DeleteRows()
 
Dim cell As Range
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("ID_value_source")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim LastRow As Long

id1 = ws.Range("A2").Value
id2 = ws.Range("A3").Value

ws2.Activate
LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ws2.Range("A" & LastRow)
    If cell.Value <> id1 And cell.Value <> id2 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Thanks
eM

Comment: `ws2.Range("A" & LastRow)` is only 1 cell, are you looking for something like `ws2.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)`? Also i think you need to loop backwards (`For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1`) as you are deleting rows.

Comment: Not sure why, but when I changed this ws2.Range to what you suggested I can remove all the rows, but I need to kind of re-run this macro twice... I don't get the idea why.

Comment: Did you loop backwards? @eM_Sk

Comment: Basically when I changed the code to ; For Each cell In ws2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow + 1) - it is giving me expected results but I need to run macro twice. When I changed to For Each cell In ws2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow -1) - it doesnt remove all the rows needed - even when I am trying to run this macro twice or more.

Comment: You are using the wrong `For` loop, please read my comment above again for the correct syntax. Alternatively you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647643/delete-entire-row-in-excel-vba?rq=1) @eM_Sk

Comment: You are making a very common mistake in VBA.  If deleting rows, you must work backwards through the range otherwise the range left to process changes each time you delete a row. ie, counting upwards deleting row three automatically makes row four the new row three and thus when you process row four you are actually processing what was row five.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update - based on the feedback & help below I managed to solve this, thank you all; this is the code that works for me:

```
Sub del_Rows()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("ID_value_source")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LastRow As Long

id1 = ws.Range("A2").Value
id2 = ws.Range("A3").Value

LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> id1 And ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> id2 Then ws2.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, you do not need `ws2.Activate`. `Activate`/`Select`are bad practice in general.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, thats really helpfull